# Почему не срабатывает такой jQuery код?

Tags: jquery, css

Почему не срабатывает такой jQuery код?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      if (window.location.pathname == '/lechenie-narkomanii.html') {
        $(".contentwidthr").css("width","100% !important");
      };
      if (window.location.pathname == '/vazhno-znat.html') {
        $(".contentwidthr").css("width","100% !important");
      };
    });
```

В чем проблема? CSS значение не заменяется...

Comment: Одного вопроса мало? http://hashcode.ru/questions/365968/javascript-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-jquery-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%83

Comment: Покажите полный код страницы для полной картины.

Comment:     $(document).ready(function(){
     if (location.pathname == "/lechenie-narkomanii.html") {
      $(".contentwidthr").css("width","100% !important");
     };
     if (location.pathname == "/vazhno-znat.html") {
      $(".contentwidthr").css("width","100% !important");
     };
    });

попробуй так что-ли...

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, js вставить "!important" не может.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824079/using-important-in-jquerys-css-function
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11733844/how-to-add-important-to-a-stylesheet-rule-using-javascript

Прогуглите про свойство style.cssText или попробуйте добавить класс к элементу. Например, так:

```
<style>
  .qwerty { 
    width: 100% !important;
  }
</style>
...
<script>
if (location.pathname == "/lechenie-narkomanii.html") {
  $(".contentwidthr").addClass("qwerty");
}
</script>
```